# Lifetime of a colab VM?

Tags: google-colaboratory

What's the maximum lifetime of a colab VM if it is left running with the browser window open (and tensorflow running)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The maximum lifetime of a VM is 12 hours.

Idle VMs time out after 90m. (As you point out, leaving a window open and running a code cell is considered active.)

Comment: Is there a way to extend the lifetime of a VM (or dump the state somehow)? Having to rerun all cells every day feels a bit redundant.