# Installing cleverhans on Colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, cleverhans

I am trying to install cleverhans (https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans)

I am running the following command

`!pip install -q -e git+http://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans.git#egg=cleverhans`

However, when I try to do `import cleverhans` I get an error saying that there's no such module.

PS If I try to install the module on my local machine, the source is stored in `~/.src/cleverhans`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the installation doesn't properly update the python path. Here's a snippet that worked for me:

```
!pip install -qq -e git+http://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans.git#egg=cleverhans
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/src/cleverhans')
import cleverhans
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Do I need to install it every time I reopen the notebook?

Comment: You'll need to re-execute that cell once for each VM. VMs are recycled after a period of inactivity; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474406