# Colaboratory notebook: Avoid re-running entire notebook after changes

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

When running colaboratory notebooks, I experience that the notebook sometimes loses it's state after making changes to one of the cells, which makes me need to rerun the entire notebook.

I am aware of the timeout at [90m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477429/8198768), however, the problem I am describing occurs well before 90m. Sometimes it happens after almost after every change I make, sometimes I do not experience any problems at all.

Any ideas how to resolve these issues?

The notebook consists of a first cell containing several import statements, including installation of mglearn using pip, a second cell fetching the data using pandas read_csv(url) and several blocks using matplotlib for plotting.

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats, display, HTML
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!pip install mglearn
import mglearn
import os
from cycler import cycler
from pprint import pprint

#the rest of this cell contains some settings for matplotlib. Moreover, warnings are silenced
```

second cell:

```
#load the data, decribe
ballframe = pd.read_csv("https://www.openml.org/data/get_csv/18626236/baseball.arff")
ballframe.describe()
```

Third cell (and more):

```
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.hist(ballframe["Year"])
```