# CancelledError: Loop execution was cancelled

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I was doing some regression analysis using google colabs and until yesterday everything was working fine but today suddenly I'm getting following error. I don't know why the training is getting stopped in the middle.

Following is the output from training:

```
 SA1 


Fold:  1



WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-8-18bba4154a19>:225: DatasetV1.make_initializable_iterator (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `for ... in dataset:` to iterate over a dataset. If using `tf.estimator`, return the `Dataset` object directly from your input function. As a last resort, you can use `tf.compat.v1.data.make_initializable_iterator(dataset)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-9-d355616e5022>:238: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-9-d355616e5022>:347: dense (from tensorflow.python.layers.core) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.dense instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-9-d355616e5022>:160: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1266: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from data/vars/SA1/feeder.cpt
Training the model with He ...
0 MAPE: 9500.299072265625
100 MAPE: 948.7984657287598
200 MAPE: 494.5207118988037
300 MAPE: 254.67548370361328
400 MAPE: 134.2471480369568
500 MAPE: 81.28451704978943
600 MAPE: 52.48984694480896

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1320 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
       1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
    -> 1407         run_metadata)
       1408 
CancelledError: Loop execution was cancelled.
     [[{{node while/LoopCond}}]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Is it possible that the VM is being killed? (see [Lifetime of a colab VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47474406))

Comment: @jdehesa It's happening every time I'm starting the training. Maybe tensorflow was updated to an unstable version yesterday. But I don't have proof of that.

Comment: We did indeed update the TF version yesterday; `tf.__version__` should be 1.13.0rc0.

Comment: Can you share a notebook that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @CraigCitro https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13LuWmVIjza-lfxuOyfWAEf_pJjtvAMEh

Comment: Could I ask you to file a github issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues with a pointer to that notebook, and noting that this only started happening in the 1.12 -> 1.13.0rc0 update?

Comment: @CraigCitro okay, I will file an issue on github. Yes, the issue started the moment tensorflow was updated from 1.12 to 1.13.0rc0

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25578 is the upstream issue if anyone else is hitting the same issue.

Comment: @CraigCitro Could you downgrade the tensorflow version to 1.12 atleast. My work is paused in the mean time.

Comment: @AnshKumar we're not going to change it for all colab users, but you can `!pip install tensorflow==1.12.0` in your notebook.